# CKeditor 5 (online builder) missing buttons

Tags: ckeditor5

Downloaded the default setup using the CKeditor v5 online builder.

When using  it all works. But when using the  to load the local (and downloaded online builder version) all the buttons are gone, why?

Help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

    <script src="/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/20.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script> -->

<body>

        <div id="editor">Test Text (buttons missing)</div>
                
        <script>
            ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
            .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
            } );
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the source code of the sample attached to a CKEditor 5 build (samples/index.html). You will notice that there is a toolbar configuration provided that you need to pass when initializing the CKEditor instance.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to copy the toolbar configuration part from the (samples/index.html) into my own html file for it to work? I guess that would be a fair assumption, bit my logic insisted that that the Online Builder would have taken care of that. So basically my bad :) Thank

Comment: I agree it's counterintuitive, we'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular users:

Even though default ckeditor build (`@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor`) brings it's own toolbar buttons,
you'll have to add it yourself for custom builds (https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/ for instance)

Copy the toolbar array generated from `theCustomBuild/sample/index.html` to your config:

html:

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [config]="config"></ckeditor>
```

in your component:

```
public config = {
    toolbar: [
        'exportPdf',
        'heading',
        '|',
        'bold',
        ...
    ]
};
```